# Why is my stored procedure not receiving its parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following stored procedure:

```
create procedure new (@user nvarchar(50))
as
Declare @ids uniqueidentifier  
set @ids = (
select id from table6 where name = @user and @ids = id)

SELECT  * from table1 as 1, table2 as 2
where 1.id = @ids
```

It's not returning the correct results - it's returning nothing. It seems that it is passing the variable (`@ids`) as empty.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get an empty result is that you are trying to use `@ids` before you have assigned anything to it. In the query where you get the value for `@ids` you are using it to filter out records where `@ids = id`, but as `@ids` is `null` at that time the result will be empty and `@ids` will remain `null`.

I assume that you just want to remove that part of the condition, unless you have some other value that you can use to compare the `id` field to.

Anyhow, I don't see how you could even create the procedure... You can't use a number as an alias, use an identifier:

```
SELECT * from table1 as t1, table2 as t2
where t1.id = @ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not *passing* `@ids` - you're *declaring* it locally.  Since it has no value, when you use in in your `WHERE` clause you get no records back, so `@ids` will be NULL.

I think you want

```
set @ids = (
select id from table6 where name = @user)
```

But you don't even need that - just do:

```
SELECT  * from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id = (select id from table6 where name = @user)
```

Which will do a `CROSS JOIN` returning every combination of records from T1 and T2.  - that may be what you *want*, just wanted to be sure to point that out.